# Is it possible to change center of rotation in GWT Canvas?

Tags: gwt, canvas

I need to draw rotated rectangle on Canvas.
I have x and y of top left rectangle corner and angle of rotation around that corner.
If I use context.rotate() function it will rotate canvas around (0,0).
Is it possible to rotate canvas around custom center on GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `context.translate` first to change the origin, thus changing the "center" of rotation. (since all rotation is done about the origin). Typically you'll want to `translate` back the same amount afterwards.

Comment: You might want to look at affine transforms as well.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html